# Passing parameters through windows task scheduler to powershell script not working

Tags: powershell, task, scheduler

Created powershell script which deletes files from folder older than X days(passing X as parameter) and scheduled it in task scheduler. 
Below is the command provided in Add arguments tab under Action in task scheduler:

```
-Command "& 'C:\Temp\Test.ps1' -DaysOld '-200'"
```

Test.ps1:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "/Temp" -File | Where-object {($._LastWriteTime lt (Get-Date).AddDays($DaysOld))| Remove-Item
```

Above is deleting all the files without considering the value `-200` passed. Have also tried with File option,nothing works.

Comment: It'd be much easier to help you troubleshoot your code, if you show it. Remember to create [mcve].

Comment: Please, use [edit] button, comments are not for providing code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare the `params` section at the beginning of your script. Good [tutorial here](https://devcentral.f5.com/s/articles/powershell-abcs-p-is-for-parameters).

Now the script expects parameter named 'DaysOld' of type `integer`.

**somefile.ps1:**

```
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=1)]
    [int]$DaysOld = 0
)

Write-Host $DaysOld
```

**Usage:**

```
powershell.exe "& '.\somefile.ps1' -DaysOld -200"
```